# What is an anonymous username supposed to look like in a ProviderInfo object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

Per Microsoft's ProfileInfo definition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileinfo.aspx, an unauthenticated profileinfo object has a username; naturally this must be keyed off of to persist/ reference profile information in a given session (I am assuming it is session-based).  I'm guessing this is some guid or something, but I don't see where this is defined, created, tracked, etc.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: No takers huh?  I'd have thought someone would know off the top of their head.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? 4.0's ProfileInfo class has an IsAnonymous (bool) property and a UserName (string) property by which you can retrieve the info you're looking for.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileinfo(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: yes, 4.0, but I don't want to know how to retrieve it, that's pretty straightforward.  I want to know how it is set, and what it looks like.  I am writing a profile provider and I want to have a clearer understanding of how anonymous profiles work in regards to creating and maintaining user names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... The question interested me so I've decided to do some research.

A bit of digging in documentation lead me first to [Implementing a Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx) MSDN article, where I've found the following:

> **GetPropertyValues method**
>
> Takes as input a SettingsContext and a SettingsPropertyCollection
>   object.
>
> The SettingsContext provides information about the user. You can use
>   the information as a primary key to retrieve profile property
>   information for the user. Use the SettingsContext object to get the
>   user name and whether the user is authenticated or anonymous.
>   ...

So, the determination of whether user is authenticated or not is generally done on higher level. Anyway, I took a look at code of Microsoft's default SqlProfileProvider implementation (namely, `GetPropertyValues` method implementation) and found out that it calls method `private void GetPropertyValuesFromDatabase(string userName, SettingsPropertyValueCollection svc)` which actually has the following code:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
...
string sName = null;

if (context != null) 
    sName = (context.Request.IsAuthenticated ? context.User.Identity.Name : context.Request.AnonymousID);
```

So, if we have a non-authenticated request then a user id is taken from `HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID` property. Searching through MSDN for this property has revealed the following page: [HttpRequest.AnonymousID property (System.Web)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.anonymousid.aspx). Although it still does not describe exact algorithm of generating this ID, but it provides information on how you can override this default algorithm if you want. All you need is to overload `public void AnonymousIdentification_Creating(Object sender, AnonymousIdentificationEventArgs e)` method in your web application. Also this page provides some information on how AnonymousID is persisted between calls (by default it's stored in `.ASPXANONYMOUS` cookie).

Example code:

```
void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize user count property
        Application["UserCount"] = 0;
    }

public void AnonymousIdentification_Creating(Object sender, AnonymousIdentificationEventArgs e)
    {
    // Change the anonymous id
    e.AnonymousID = "mysite.com_Anonymous_User_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    // Increment count of unique anonymous users
    Application["UserCount"] = Int32.Parse(Application["UserCount"].ToString()) + 1;
}
```

**Summary:** I have not been able to answer your original question on HOW this ID is created by default but I think that last code snippet will be enough for you to override this with any algorithm you want.

Comment: Excellect.  This was exactly what I was looking for, actually.  Thank you!